# Iterative commands to across different tables with forEach and/or toArray

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I need to iterate through a primary table and add new documents to a different table each with `id:` and `name:` entries that match documents in the primary table.

I have read the [relevant documentation](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#for_each), which is shamefully sparse, and I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864052/rethinkdb-iterating-over-object-properties) about iterating over object properties inside of the same table, but this doesnt apply since I want to iterate over objects over a table, not properties in an object, and apply the results to a NEW table (rather than the same table).

Can I iterate through the length of the table and create documents matching certain fields in a new table?

More specifically:  Documents in my DB's `primary_table` have fields `id:` and `name.` How do I migrate these id's and corresponding names to a table that details `payment_history` using one or a combination of `forEach` , `toArray`, and `next`?

My attempt:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').forEach(
  function(id){
    return r.db('client')table('payment_history').insert(
      {
       id: r.db('client').table('basic_info').get(id).getField('id'),  
       name: r.db('client').table('basic_info').get(id).getField('name')
       }  
      );
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the `forEach` like this:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').forEach(function(row) {
  return r.db('client').table('payment_history').insert(
    {id: row('id'), name: row('name')});})
```

But it would probably be better to write it like this:

```
r.db('client').table('payment_history').insert(
  r.db('client').table('basic_info').pluck('id', 'name'))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your first suggestion helped me understand the mechanics of forEach. One thing: your answer is missing a quote!

Comment: Also: will the second solution iterate through all of the id's in the basic_info table?

Comment: Kind of.  What it does is it takes the `basic_info` table (as a lazy stream), strips every document in it down to just the two fields you want, and then lazily inserts that stream into `payment_history`.  It should perform better than the `forEach` version because it can take advantage of batching in the inserts.

Comment: You said it's a stream. So does that mean that it syncs payment_history with thr entries in basic_ info?

Comment: No, it won't do any sort of synchronization, it will just insert the documents once.  A stream just means that you don't have to load all the data into memory at once.